# Strange ClassCastException from Double to Integer on android

Tags: java, android, classcastexception

I build a android widget, and in the WidgetService class which extends BroadcastReceiver.

A vary strange thing happens, when I try to get an integer from an ArrayList, it throws an exception

```
public class WidgetService extends BroadcastReceiver {
      int currentIndex = -1;
      ArrayList<Integer> indexHitTimes = null;
      ArrayList<Integer> staredIndex = null;
      HashMap<Integer, Integer> staredIndexHitTimes = null;
      ...
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            ...
            updateCurrentIndex();
            ...
      }
      private void updateCurrentIndex(){
            ...
            Random r = new Random();
            int size = staredIndex.size();
            int randomIndex = r.nextInt(size);
            currentIndex = staredIndex.get(randomIndex);    ->problem here
            currentIndexHitTimes = staredIndexHitTimes.get(currentIndex);
            minHitTimes = Collections.min(staredIndexHitTimes.values());
            ...
      }
}
```

I have check if it was caused by NullPointer though, no clue.

Is it the problem with my jdk (version 1.8.0_74) or android studio ?(version 1.51)
Android SDK Version: 6.0(but I have tried 4.4, still the same)

I try to start a new project and copy to it, but still not working.

How is it possible?
Since "staredIndex" is an ArrayList with Integer paramater and randomIndex is an int, currentIndex is and int.

Where is "Double" from?

How to solve it?

Error Message

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver 
heart.david.jp50_reviewer.WidgetService: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2602)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:147)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1358)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
at heart.david.jp50_reviewer.WidgetService.updateCurrentIndex(WidgetService.java:136)
at heart.david.jp50_reviewer.WidgetService.onReceive(WidgetService.java:51)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2595)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:147) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1358) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

> Thanks everyone. The problem I found is here. The code below initialize the ArrayList.

```
        ...
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext());
        String json = sharedPreferences.getString("staredIndex", null);
        if(json == null){
            staredIndex = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i=0;i<hashMap_Characters.size();i++){
                boolean stared = hashMap_Stared.get(i);
                if(stared){
                    staredIndex.add(i);
                }
            }
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String staredIndex_json = gson.toJson(staredIndex);
            editor.putString("staredIndex", staredIndex_json);
            editor.commit();
        }else{
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            staredIndex = gson.fromJson(json, ArrayList.class); -> here! the staredIndex filled with Doubles!
        }
        ...
```

> Then I change to this, and the problem is completely solved.

```
        ...
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext());
        String json = sharedPreferences.getString("indexHitTimes", null);
        if(json == null){
            indexHitTimes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i=0;i<hashMap_Characters.size();i++){
                indexHitTimes.add(0);
            }
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Integer>>(){}.getType();
            String indexHitTimes_json = gson.toJson(indexHitTimes, type);
            editor.putString("indexHitTimes", indexHitTimes_json);
            editor.commit();
        }else{
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            indexHitTimes = (ArrayList<Integer>)gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Integer>>(){}.getType());
        }
        ...
```

Comment: `int currentIndex = -1;` can be declared as `Integer currentIndex = -1`.

Comment: You don't show the code that fills `staredIndex`, so we can't tell you how a `Double` value sneaked in there. Remember, at runtime `ArrayList<Integer>` is really just an untyped `ArrayList`, so any type of object can be in there, if you mistreat the list.

Comment: See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/U3ouWS) example for how a `Double` can exist in an `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is coming because ArrayList staredIndex contains different type of data.ArrayList contains Double and Integer type data but you have declare staredIndex ArrayList as Integer.You should have to only add integer type data in your ArrayList or You should do type casting from Double to Integer.

Comment: thanks you. I think I have found the problem, post below.

Comment: Please post your solution

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Double d = staredIndex.get(randomIndex);
currentIndex = d.intValue();
```

Or

```
currentIndex = (int) staredIndex.get(randomIndex);
```

If you want to cast from `double` to `int`.

Comment: Thanks you. But my problem is not casting from Double to Integer.